# How to send a notification instead of a message when user is offline using socket.io

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

So whenever another user is offline and an online user tries to send a message, it returns an error. The error is caused because it didn't find a socket where the user is in, but I can console.log something from the error response, since I put it in if/else block. So i was wondering how could I send a response to the client and push a notification for the user who is offline. The explanation is probably confusing, so here is the code:

index.js(socket):

```
const io = require('socket.io')(8900, {
  cors: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  },
});

let users = [];

const addUser = (userId, socketId) => {
  !users.some((user) => user.userId === userId) &&
    users.push({ userId, socketId });
};

const removeUser = (socketId) => {
  users = users.filter((user) => user.socketId !== socketId);
};

const getUser = (userId) => {

  return foundUser = users.find((user) => user.userId === userId)

};

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  //when ceonnect
  console.log('a user connected.');

  //take userId and socketId from user
  socket.on('addUser', (userId) => {
    addUser(userId, socket.id);
    io.emit('getUsers', users);
  });

  //send and get message
  socket.on('sendMessage', ({ senderId, recieverId, text }) => {
    const user = getUser(recieverId);
    console.log('RECIEVERRRR', user);

    if (user) {
      io.to(user.socketId).emit('getMessage', {
        senderId,
        text,
      });
    } else {
              // IMPORTANT: This is where I can console.log the error, but can't figure out how to send the response to the client
    }
  });

  //when disconnect
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('a user disconnected!');
    removeUser(socket.id);
    io.emit('getUsers', users);
  });
});
```

dashboard.js (I cut out most of the code, but this is where i'm sending request to socket):

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const message = {
      sender: user._id,
      text: newMessage,
      conversationId: currentChat._id,
    };

    const recieverId = currentChat.members.find(
      (member) => member !== user._id
    );

    console.log('REC from FRONT END', recieverId);

    socket.current.emit('sendMessage', {
      senderId: user._id,
      recieverId,
      text: newMessage,
    });

    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post('/api/messages/addMessage', message);
      setMessages([...messages, data]);
      setNewMessage('');
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can emit a new event `sendMessageFailed`:

```
  //send and get message
  socket.on('sendMessage', ({ senderId, recieverId, text }) => {
    const user = getUser(recieverId);
    console.log('RECIEVERRRR', user);

    if (user) {
      io.to(user.socketId).emit('getMessage', {
        senderId,
        text,
      });
    } else {
      io.to(user.socketId).emit('sendMessageFailed', "Your friend is offline");
    }
  });
```

At the client side listen to the event:

```
  socket.current.on('sendMessageFailed',  (err) => {
    //Sending message has failed!
  });
```

Comment: Yes, I thought so myself, but the thing is that getUser function needs the recieverId to check in which room he is, but due to the fact that the reciever is offline, the user is undefined.